# beautiful soup need help finding multiple tags

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, tags

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from lxml import etree
import requests
import re

URL = "https://csimarket.com/stocks/at_glance.php?code=AA"

HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36', \
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
raw_html = soup.find(href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")
span = raw_html.find("span")
span.decompose()
print(raw_html.text.strip())
```

code works fine raw_html = soup.find(href="../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=100")
as I am going thru other pages this part will different ../Industry/Industry_Data.php?s=1000

how do I search for just "../Industry/Industry_Data.php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select your elements with `css selectors` and check if `<span>` exists:

```
for a in soup.select('a[href*="../Industry/Industry_Data.php"]'):
    if a.span:
        a.span.decompose()
    print(a.text.strip())
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = "https://csimarket.com/stocks/at_glance.php?code=AA"

HEADERS = ({'User-Agent':
                'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 \
            (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36', \
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'})

webpage = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS)
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.select('a[href*="../Industry/Industry_Data.php"]'):
    if a.span:
        a.span.decompose()
    print(a.text.strip())
```

##### Output

```
Industries At a Glance
Basic Materials
Aluminum
Aluminum
Basic Materials
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. What does `decompose()` mean?

Comment: You still used it in your code - *decompose() removes a tag from the tree,...* in this case the `<span>` with bullet point - [From the docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose)